# WebAssembly LinkError When Standard Library is Included

Tags: javascript, c, webassembly

This very simple WebAssembly program works fine for me:

**test.c**

```c
int testing(void) {
    return 10;
}
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

**test.html**

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var imports = {};

            function instantiate(bytes, imports) {
                return WebAssembly.compile(bytes).then(m => new WebAssembly.Instance(m, imports));
            }
            fetch('test.wasm').then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
                .then(bytes => instantiate(bytes, imports))
                .then(instance => { 
                    console.log(instance.exports._testing());
                } );

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using:

```sh
emcc test.c something.c -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_testing']" -s WASM=1 -O3 -o test.wasm
```

But then, if I try something like:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int testing(void) {
    printf("Hello!\n");
    return 10;
}
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

First, it produces this error:

```
TypeError: import object field 'env' is not an Object
```

Which I've tried to solve by adding an `env` field to `imports`:

```js
var imports = {
    env: {
        memoryBase: 0,
        tableBase: 0,
        memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({
            initial: 512
        }),
        table: new WebAssembly.Table({
            initial: 0,
            element: 'anyfunc'
        })
    }
};
```

But this just gives me another error:

```
LinkError: import object field '___syscall146' is not a Function
```

I've also tried using `-s EXPORT_ALL=1`, but that just slightly changed the error message:

```
LinkError: import object field '___setErrNo' is not a Function
```

I don't really know much about WebAssembly, so I'm not sure what's going on here. What exactly is causing this error?

**Edit:**

Interestingly, I don't get any error at all if I call `malloc`:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
int testing(void) {
    int* p = malloc(5);
    *p = 17;
    free(p);
    return 7;
}
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

But if I return values from any allocated memory:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
int testing(void) {
    int* p = malloc(5);
    *p = 17;
    free(p);
    return *p;
}
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

I get this again:

```
LinkError: import object field '___setErrNo' is not a Function
```

From the error message it seems like `emcc` isn't linking the standard library (maybe?), but I can't find anyone else with the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by getting `emcc` to output a `.js` file directly:

**test.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void testing(void) {
    printf("Hello!\n");
}

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

**test.html**

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script>
        Module.onRuntimeInitialized = function() {
            _testing();
        }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

```sh
emcc test.c -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_testing'] -s WASM=1 -O3 -o test.js
```

I'm still not entirely sure what was wrong before... but at least it's working now.